# Is it possible to call java method from C code with SWIG generated JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

I am trying to use SWIG to generate my JNI. I already have JNI code that is working, but it is hand written and it is getting more and more complicated and difficult to maintain.

Some of my functions in C are called from Java, and then they call some methods in Java (probably it is not a good idea, but it is working for now)...

I am wondering if it is possible for SWIG to generate that kind of JNI code?

Comment: Do you mean a tool to generate code that uses FindClass, GetMethodID, CallVoidMethod, and what not?

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes, something like that.

Comment: @TomBlodget Or at least to generate code that gives me JNIEnv , jclass and jobjects to work with, without manualy forwarding from wrapper files...

Comment: c++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190556/how-to-call-java-from-c-using-swig

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should be possible.

> The following languages are also supported in swig-1.3.6 onwards:
>   Java JDK 1.1 and newer.

Quoted from http://www.swig.org/compat.html

More info here:

- http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#imclass
- http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus

**UPDATE**: For more info on calling Java from C++ have a look at: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_directors

Comment: It is easy to generate JNI code with SWIG for calling C from Java, I have done that already. But my problem is the other direction, calling Java methods from C functions. So this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @ddss I've updated my answer with another link that I hope you'll find useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is c++, and my code is pure c.

Answer (score 0):

The only JNI wrappers of this type I'm aware of are [Jace](http://code.google.com/p/jace/) and [JunC++ion](http://codemesh.com/products/junction/), both of which are C++ based so don't fit your needs.